# Can't format USB drive

Tags: usb, usb-drive, format, umount

I have a 4 Gig USB drive that I'd like to format.

I go to the Disk Utility, and try to format it, but it says that the device is busy. (This same error occurs no matter whether I tried to format the whole drive, or just the partition.)

So, I do some research, and figured out how to disable automount. It's now disabled.

To be on the safe side, I first unplug then reconnect the USB stick then tried:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
sudo umount /dev/sdb*
```

Now, the Disk Utility STILL gives me the same error - usually "/dev/sdb is busy" or "/dev/sdb1 is mounted" or similar.

Comment: Why don't you use GParted which will allow you to unmount from the context menu and do whatever you want to do (chech, format, label, etc.) easily?

Comment: Oh, man, I forgot about GParted. I had that a while back, I loved it. After I had to reinstall Ubuntu, I sort of forgot about it... Thanks for reminding me about that! I actually figured out the problem, though: I'd left the Startup Disk Creator open, and for some reason, it was auto-mounting my flash drive...

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/1059872

Comment: what do you have when you type "mount | grep sdb"

Answer (score 1):

Run `df -h` in terminal and make sure there is nothing mounted that looks like `/dev/sdb*`.
I had `/dev/sdb11/` and `/dev/sdb8` mounted so I had to run `umount /dev/sdb11` and `umount /dev/sdb8`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the disk was umounted and the problem persisted. I had to use gparted to delete the partition, restart (as requested by the app) and try to format it again. After that I was able to.

Comment: In my case even "delete partition" option was unavailable. I had to format to "cleared" with GParted and than I was able to create new partition table.